# How do I search element for certain color inside div?

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to get id for an `i` element with a certain color inside look_here div. How do I do this with find?

```js
$("#look_here i").each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).css("color") == "rgb(143, 187, 94)") {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);
  }
});
```

```css
#i1 { color: rgb(143, 187, 94) }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" />
<div id="look_here">
  <i id="i3" class="fa fa-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="i1" class="fa fa-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="i2" class="fa fa-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57456208/edit) then `[<>]` stack snippet editor and add relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: The answer is you likely cannot unless the `i` has a parsable attribute set, but that I cannot answer without seeing your HTML

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with the relevant CSS. Your code works when I do   `#i1 { color: rgb(143, 187, 94) }`

Comment: And why not use a loop - if there are no attributes on the I that can be used, you need a loop.

Comment: Ok it seems that my question is written in a good way now. Thanks. Now I am just waiting for a answer that uses find in the right way.

Comment: What is the usecase. I assume there is no need to test that #i1 is green when you set it to green in the CSS. If you use a class and jQuery to set the class, then you can just query the class: `alert($("i.green").attr("id"))`

Comment: mplungjan, It is used as a simple radio button that I set to green when I click on it. I am not using a class to set the color, just setting the color with .css()

Comment: So don't. Set a class!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jquery [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also what do you think the find does under the hood?

Comment: There are better ways my friend

Comment: _Technically_, this is still a loop

Comment: GROVER, So you mean that it's still a loop even if I use find?

Answer (score 0):

Please do this:

```js
$("#look_here").on("click","i",function() {
  $(this)
  .addClass("checked")
  .siblings().removeClass("checked");
})
$("#but").on("click",function() {
  var id = $("#look_here i.checked").attr("id")
  console.log(id?id:"none checked")
})
```

```css
.checked { color: rgb(143, 187, 94) }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" />
<div id="look_here">
  <i id="i3" class="fa fa-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="i1" class="fa fa-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i id="i2" class="fa fa-circle fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div><br/>
<button type="button" id="but">Which one?</button>
```